# Getting the URL of the page code is embedded in

Tags: javascript, url

I have a piece of javascript code. Right now it forces users to manually enter the url of the page they want to insert it on. This is kind of a hassle. Is there a way I can fetch the url of the page in automatically and make everyone's life easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

Comment: Of course, you'll have to use 'window.location.href' to get the actual URL (window.location just returns the Location object).